# How to get system IOPS and disk IOPS in java/scala

Tags: java, scala

What's the best way to get the total system IOPS and per-disk IOPS from within a java or scala program?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This information is not directly available in java. It is going to be OS dependent and to some degree disk volume manager specific.
If you are using linux, [nmon](http://nmon.sourceforge.net/pmwiki.php) is a nice tool to use for watching io.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I'm interested in essentially querying these stats and inserting them into a db. There are other stats that are being collected as part of this same job, which is implemented in java, so I'm wondering if there's a more direct way. At the worst, I would need to execute an external program such as iostat and parse the output, but I'm hoping there's a better way to obtain this information.

Comment: You could read and parse the /proc/diskstats file directly. https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ABI/testing/procfs-diskstats  http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/suse-novell-60/interpreting-proc-diskstats-360350/